# Symbol's function definition is void: org-export--get-global-options

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

I use a lot of embedded latex in my org files with drill mode. It worked fine with org 8, but recently I've upgraded to org 9, and now when I run `C-c C-x C-l` I'll get this error. My `.emacs` file contains the following code related with org and latex:

```
(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvipng) 
(setq org-format-latex-options (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5))
```

I'm new to Emacs. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Function `org-export--get-global-options` has not been defined. Perhaps it was replaced by something else in the Org code. Or perhaps it is defined in an Org file that you have not loaded. Look for it in the Org code. If it is not there then compare the current Org code with the last version, to find out what replaced it - and use whatever replaced it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is solved. I just added

```
(require 'ox)
```